# Set iFrame as divs background

Tags: css, google-maps, html, iframe

I'm trying to set an iframe (embeded google maps iframe to be exact) as a divs background in my site.

So basically you'll have a div with headings, paragraphs and the works in side. But as the background you'll have the map iframe. Still fully functionaly etc. etc.

What's the easiest way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll suggest to use two containers one over each other. Position them absolutely.

Comment: Oooh nooooo! A down vote!!! lol.. XD

Comment: Btw your suggestion worked @Krasmir, if you set it as an answer I will except, thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a way of setting an iframe as a div background, but why don't you just `z-index` one div on top of an iframe? That way you can can display your info in the div and it won't affect the iframe behind it.